# Reversing the integration order

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

> Consider the iterated integral$$\int_1^{\sqrt{2}}\int_{-\sqrt{2-x^2}}^{\sqrt{2-x^2}} (e-e^{x^2+y^2})dy\,dx.$$
>   (Do not try to evaluate it!)
>
> (a) Change the order of integration in this integral (so that the inner integral is with respect to $x$, and the outer integral is with respect to $y$.)

I believe the answer would be like this:

$$ \int_{-\sqrt{2-y^2}}^{\sqrt{2-y^2}}\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy. $$

If anyone could check my work and point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: The answer to what?

Comment: The integral should be a value and not a function of $y$. So the answer you give is wrong. But give your logic reasoning? Also draw out the original region and that can give you hints :).

Comment: The outer limits of integration should be constants.

Comment: @Chinny84: The Domain is 1 < x < sqrt(2) and -sqrt(2-x^2) < y < sqrt(2-x^2)

So I drew out the region and found where the first integration starts and ends and that would be from x = 1 to x = sqrt(2), so I set those to my inner bounds, while the bounds in the y direction would be the function: + or - sqrt(2-y^2)

Comment: Yes but you should swap the integration around since as it stands the usual interpretation is that you have the last limits having the variable y in it? if you gave the integral to someone on Mars they would get the wrong result to the one (I think ) you have in your head.

Answer (score 0):

Since the outer integral is with respect to $y$, slice the region at a fixed value of $y$. We want to find the bounds for $x$ in this cross-section in terms of $y$. You'll notice that the lower bound is just the vertical line $x = 1$, and the upper bound is the circular part given by $x = \sqrt{2 - y^2}$. Since the vertical line intersects the circle at $(1, 1)$ and $(1, -1)$, we obtain:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 \int_1^{\sqrt{2 - y^2}} f(x,y) \, dx \, dy
$$